# How to send "Subject Alternative Name" data from SSL certificate with Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf, x509

My users are connecting to my app thanks to a smartcard containing a certificate. I am using httpd to make sure the certificate is valid:

`SSLCACertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/certs/usersCA.crt"`

It works fine but I'd like to know who my user is on the server side (a spring app running on tomcat).

The certificate contains a unique ID which I can use to know who the user is. Unfortunately it's stored in the subjectAltName (http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName).

For reference the "openssl.cnf" used during the certificate generation contains:

```
subjectAltName = dirName:alt_names
[alt_names]
description="Id=123456789"
```

I know that with httpd I can transfer the certificate data to http headers that my server will be able to handle. For example with:

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
```

I get the DN subject.

But I can't find a way to get my Id stored in the subject alternative name. With SSL_CLIENT_SAN_Email_n or SSL_CLIENT_SAN_DNS_n I can get DNS or email data but I can't find a way to get my data stored here:

```
Requested Extensions:
X509v3 Basic Constraints:
    CA:FALSE
X509v3 Key Usage:
    Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DirName:/description=Id=123456789
```

Do you know which httpd directive I can use to send my data through http header?

Thanks.