# How to get “Subject Alternative Name” data from SSL certificate with Tomcat HTTPD?

Tags: authentication, ssl, tomcat, smartcard

First, I'm not a Java or a Tomcat developer.  I have a third party Tomcat server that does not support smartcards; unfortunately, where I work requires administrators to use smartcards for everything, and I'm tired of getting a temporary password every time I need to log in.

I have gotten to the point where I can use my smartcard to log into the server, but it's not using a useful userid.  Instead, I am logged in with the user id "CN=1234567, OU=people, O=example, C=us".  When I log in, I am prompted to choose a certificate, but only one option is provided, for the only cert with "Key Usage: Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation (c0)".  That certificate's subject matches the user id I'm getting, but there is also a Subject Alternative Name with two values.  One is a URL and one an RFC822 Name.  That last is what I would prefer to use, as I think I can use it to find my AD group memberships and the like.

I've found a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942856) indicating that I could set an HTTP header to access the SAN, but the question has never been answered.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Comment: The question you mention is for Apache. From [mod_ssl doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_ssl.html) it seems there is another field `SSL_CLIENT_SAN_OTHER_msUPN_n` that can be accessed